# Why can I start video manually, but not in rc.local?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gstreamer

On Raspberry Pi I run a client program written in Python. It communicates over tcp messages with the server. When the appropriate command comes from the server, the program starts the video transmission:

```
subprocess.check_call(['/home/pi/to_janus.sh'],shell = True)
```

While I start the client manually, video by command from the server is started. But if I set the start of client to `rc.local`, I get the following error messages, when the command comes from the server:

```
(gst-plugin-scanner:839): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type 'GstOMXAudioSink'

(gst-plugin-scanner:839): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed

(gst-plugin-scanner:839): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed

(gst-plugin-scanner:839): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_register_static: assertion 'parent_type > 0' failed

(gst-plugin-scanner:839): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed
```

(The same messages I get if I try to run the video directly via `rc.local`). 
At the same time, the client successfully exchanges messages, and the result does not depend on how quickly the command to start transmitting video comes.
I don't understand how the system knows that I started the client not manually, but through `rc.local`. And what I have to do to be able to work without manual loading.

**to_janus.sh:**

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! image/jpeg,width=1280,height=480,framerate=20/1 ! jpegdec ! videoflip method=rotate-180 ! omxh264enc target-bitrate=1000000 control-rate=variable ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=192.168.1.2 port=8004 sync=false
```

Comment: `shell=True` is an error (though you won't get an error message) when the argument is a list. You specifically want `shell=False` here. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess

Comment: This looks like you are trying to launch an X11 program when there is not yet an X11 session. You will need to start the X server first. This is a common FAQ.

Comment: Launch video after the startup of the program was working after add 2 lines:
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')